# Good Python tools for object detection (circles) in blurry images

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection

So I have [TEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_electron_microscopy) images, that look like this:

[image: TEM]

Is there a Python module I can use to help me analyze this image, in particular, detect the atoms (circles) in the picture?

The image quality of the TEMs is pretty bad so I need an approach that is robust enough to distinguish what is an atom and what is not.

I can easily enough open the picture using PIL and do things with it, but I was hoping to find an algorithm that could detect the circles.

If there is not a tool like this, does anyone know how I would go about making my own algorithm to do this?

Comment: I know that a Hough transform is a technique used to accomplish things like this. Perhaps that will help you in your search?

Comment: Take a look at OpenCV, and/or Tesseract, but I'm not sure how much success you'll have. My human eye can barely detect where the circles are in that picture. Getting a tool or library to do it might be near impossible.

Comment: @andenthal That is what I was worried about. I'll give them a shot, but I think it is back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: I did a quick search and found [this](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python/blob/master/Official_Tutorial_Python_Codes/3_imgproc/houghcircles.py). Check it out, it might be what you're looking for. Edit: And don't be so quick to give up...

Comment: @Lanaru I am not giving up yet I want to try all possible solutions. I am just hesitant about the results.

Comment: Nobody can - without a precise specification.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt to count the number of atoms in your picture, using OpenCV. It's sort of a hokey approach but yields decent results. First blur the picture a little bit, then threshold it, and then find resulting contours.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('atoms.png')
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(
    image,
    cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 
    )
image2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(
    image2, 
    ksize=(9,9), 
    sigmaX=8,
    sigmaY=8,
    )
cv2.imwrite('blurred.png', image2)
hello, image2 = cv2.threshold(
    image2,
    thresh=95,
    maxval=255,
    type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
    )
cv2.imwrite('thresholded.png', image2)
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(
    image2,  # Note: findContours() changes the image.
    mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,
    )
print('Number of contours: {0}'.format(len(contours)))
cv2.drawContours(
    image,
    contours=contours,
    contourIdx=-1,
    color=(0,255,0),
    thickness=2,
    )
cv2.imwrite('augmented.png', image)
cv2.imshow('hello', image)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
```

And the stdout output was:

```
Number of contours: 46
```

Spend some time fiddling with the Gaussian Blur and threshold parameters, and I bet you can get even more accurate results.

Comment: Wow this looks pretty good. I will have to take a closer look at it Monday morning.

Comment: This is a great answer and this question should not have been closed.