# Finding connected/continuous shapes

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, graph-theory, shapes

See below for an example pictures. I have a list of cells (red boxes) I am assembling into a network. I'd like to find the largest continuous shapes (Image 2) that the cells form. I've attempted a few different algorithms, but so far, have not quite achieved the desired output (Image 2). Any tips or advice to push me in the right direction would be extremely helpful. I've included a sample set of cells below for experimentation.

[image]
[image]

```
{'R: 2 C: 2': array([[108.8854942 ,  87.94061039],
       [110.82578328,  91.90519524],
       [117.75909304,  91.73789114],
       [115.50550647,  85.82580305],
       [108.8854942 ,  87.94061039]]), 'R: 3 C: 1': array([[113.25191989,  79.91371496],
       [115.50550647,  85.82580305],
       [120.07933621,  79.95254025],
       [118.52744504,  73.95826139],
       [113.25191989,  79.91371496]]), 'R: 3 C: 2': array([[115.50550647,  85.82580305],
       [117.75909304,  91.73789114],
       [121.63122739,  85.94681911],
       [120.07933621,  79.95254025],
       [115.50550647,  85.82580305]]), 'R: 12 C: 0': array([[175.59132308,  44.03815188],
       [171.56138902,  47.36290359],
       [178.90235173,  49.87364559],
       [183.11866575,  47.8392923 ],
       [175.59132308,  44.03815188]]), 'R: 13 C: 0': array([[183.11866575,  47.8392923 ],
       [178.90235173,  49.87364559],
       [184.41041112,  55.46974661],
       [188.27102302,  54.59199885],
       [183.11866575,  47.8392923 ]]), 'R: 15 C: 0': array([[192.13998449,  62.18992926],
       [188.10333294,  62.48387562],
       [189.39657291,  70.19183518],
       [193.02702586,  70.52421185],
       [192.13998449,  62.18992926]]), 'R: 15 C: 1': array([[188.10333294,  62.48387562],
       [184.06668139,  62.77782199],
       [185.76611995,  69.85945851],
       [189.39657291,  70.19183518],
       [188.10333294,  62.48387562]]), 'R: 15 C: 2': array([[184.06668139,  62.77782199],
       [180.03002984,  63.07176835],
       [182.135667  ,  69.52708183],
       [185.76611995,  69.85945851],
       [184.06668139,  62.77782199]]), 'R: 16 C: 0': array([[193.02702586,  70.52421185],
       [189.39657291,  70.19183518],
       [189.56842104,  78.17781652],
       [193.30760166,  79.00577592],
       [193.02702586,  70.52421185]]), 'R: 17 C: 0': array([[193.30760166,  79.00577592],
       [189.56842104,  78.17781652],
       [187.59263169,  85.45582689],
       [191.14404507,  86.55016022],
       [193.30760166,  79.00577592]]), 'R: 18 C: 0': array([[191.14404507,  86.55016022],
       [187.59263169,  85.45582689],
       [185.00687754,  92.69699062],
       [189.06971865,  94.44091623],
       [191.14404507,  86.55016022]]), 'R: 18 C: 1': array([[187.59263169,  85.45582689],
       [184.04121831,  84.36149355],
       [180.94403643,  90.95306501],
       [185.00687754,  92.69699062],
       [187.59263169,  85.45582689]]), 'R: 19 C: 0': array([[189.06971865,  94.44091623],
       [185.00687754,  92.69699062],
       [181.95964032, 100.03226958],
       [186.10359692, 102.35389887],
       [189.06971865,  94.44091623]]), 'R: 19 C: 1': array([[185.00687754,  92.69699062],
       [180.94403643,  90.95306501],
       [177.81568372,  97.71064028],
       [181.95964032, 100.03226958],
       [185.00687754,  92.69699062]]), 'R: 20 C: 0': array([[186.10359692, 102.35389887],
       [181.95964032, 100.03226958],
       [177.56436653, 106.67161598],
       [180.91182192, 109.17013501],
       [186.10359692, 102.35389887]]), 'R: 20 C: 2': array([[177.81568372,  97.71064028],
       [173.67172713,  95.38901099],
       [170.86945576, 101.67457793],
       [174.21691114, 104.17309695],
       [177.81568372,  97.71064028]]), 'R: 21 C: 0': array([[180.91182192, 109.17013501],
       [177.56436653, 106.67161598],
       [173.22261725, 113.27659649],
       [176.2146574 , 116.10293774],
       [180.91182192, 109.17013501]]), 'R: 21 C: 2': array([[174.21691114, 104.17309695],
       [170.86945576, 101.67457793],
       [167.23853697, 107.623914  ],
       [170.23057711, 110.45025525],
       [174.21691114, 104.17309695]]), 'R: 22 C: 2': array([[170.23057711, 110.45025525],
       [167.23853697, 107.623914  ],
       [162.4463498 , 112.73298919],
       [164.97317473, 115.81312208],
       [170.23057711, 110.45025525]]), 'R: 23 C: 0': array([[170.02682459, 121.97338787],
       [167.49999966, 118.89325498],
       [161.64892911, 124.22465629],
       [164.09321621, 128.08732603],
       [170.02682459, 121.97338787]]), 'R: 24 C: 2': array([[159.204642  , 120.36198654],
       [156.7603549 , 116.4993168 ],
       [151.65523338, 121.16584233],
       [153.47750221, 124.96830275],
       [159.204642  , 120.36198654]]), 'R: 25 C: 0': array([[157.12203987, 132.57322359],
       [155.29977104, 128.77076317],
       [148.18673938, 132.27948927],
       [149.47446073, 136.22308875],
       [157.12203987, 132.57322359]]), 'R: 25 C: 2': array([[153.47750221, 124.96830275],
       [151.65523338, 121.16584233],
       [145.61129668, 124.39229032],
       [146.89901803, 128.3358898 ],
       [153.47750221, 124.96830275]]), 'R: 26 C: 0': array([[149.47446073, 136.22308875],
       [148.18673938, 132.27948927],
       [140.78782347, 134.97215307],
       [141.52838086, 138.97081892],
       [149.47446073, 136.22308875]]), 'R: 26 C: 2': array([[146.89901803, 128.3358898 ],
       [145.61129668, 124.39229032],
       [139.30670868, 126.97482135],
       [140.04726607, 130.97348721],
       [146.89901803, 128.3358898 ]])}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a graph with connected nodes? The problem should then reduce to finding the connected component with the largest size, which is easily solvable

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Any recommendations on how to create such a graph? Would something like networkx work?

Comment: He wants all the components ( sometimes called cliques ), not just the largest.  Google 'graph components' and you will get lots of algorithms and sample code.

Comment: @ravenspoint ah, thank you for the tip. That search did indeed return examples and info that match what I am looking to do. Thanks!

Comment: @kjans_tbme, looking for contours as proxies for discrete objects may be of potential use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116465/1510289